# Firebase cannot signup users with email and password

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am using firebase to signup users using email and password on my website. I have enabled email and password signup on my console. When I signup an user on the web page, the user email and password do not get passed to Firebase, and no error is displayed neither.

Her is my front end code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Registration </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="signup.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>    
  <form id="form">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Sign up as a Language Learner</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="password1" type="password" name="password_1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="password2" type="password" name="password_2" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p id="message">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <button id="register_button" class="btn" name="signup">Register</button>
        <p class="input">Already a member? <a href="login.html">Sign in</a>
       &nbsp <a href="/">Cancel</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="signup_success">
    <h2>Sign-up Successful!</h2>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my signup.js file:

```
var password2 = document.querySelector("#password2").value;
var register_button = document.querySelector("#register_button");
var config = {
  apiKey: "111",
  authDomain: "222",
  databaseURL: "333",
  projectId: "444",
  storageBucket: "555",
  messagingSenderId: "666"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

register_button.onclick = function() {
  var email = document.querySelector("#email").value;
  var password1 = document.querySelector("#password1").value;
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password1).catch(function(error) {
    alert("hello");
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    document.querySelector("#message").innerHTML = errorCode + ": " + errorMessage;
  })
}
```

I have my config setup properly with the data from the console. If I get rid of `register_button.onclick = function()`, the `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword` executes. I tried to add `register_button.addEventListener("click", register_user, false);` at the end and it does not work either.

I have no idea what is wrong with this, any help and advice is very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

*Edit: Thanks to @Fire-in-D-Hole below, it was due to my  tag in HTML, using  tag messes up with what we submit on Firebase. Lesson learned: never use  when using Firebase

Comment: How doesn't it work? Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is absolutely Correct. However, There seems to be an Extra Space in the method `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password1)` which is causing the issue.

Please change it to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password1)`.

Also, When I click on Register it seems you are using `Form Tag`and the values are being displayed in the Address bar(See Below). Suggest you to Please check as you might not want to show Details in the Address bar.
[image]

Users Registered Screenshot:

[image]

Lastly, you are using Two fields as password make sure you have the logic Written that both the password fields have to be matched. Adding the Code below which I tried and it doesn't have Form tags.

```js
var password2 = document.querySelector("#password2").value;
var register_button = document.querySelector("#register_button");



  var config = {
    apiKey: "111",
    authDomain: "1111",
    databaseURL: "1111",
    projectId: "1111",
    storageBucket: "11111",
    messagingSenderId: "111"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);


register_button.onclick = function() {
  var email = document.querySelector("#email").value;
  var password1 = document.querySelector("#password1").value;
  var password2= document.querySelector("#password2").value;

  //alert("heyman im in register button");
  //console.log("Email" +email);
 // console.log("password1 Value" +password1);
 // console.log("password2 Value" +password2);

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password1).catch(function(error) {
    //alert("hello");
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    document.querySelector("#message").innerHTML = errorCode + ": " + errorMessage;
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Registration </title>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="signup.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>    
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Sign up as a Language Learner</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="password1" type="password" name="password_1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="password2" type="password" name="password_2" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p id="message">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <button id="register_button" class="btn" name="signup">Register</button>
        <p class="input">Already a member? <a href="login.html">Sign in</a>
       &nbsp <a href="/">Cancel</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  <div id="signup_success">
    <h2>Sign-up Successful!</h2>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `.onAuthStateChanged` observer to handle the signin state change.

Comment: I highly doubt this is the answer. This question is about not being able to create an account and not the logging in.

Comment: Hi Ron, how do I implement .onAuthStateChanged for user signup? Thanks